# Server error: Internal server error: module 'google.auth.credentials' has no attribute 'CredentialsWithTokenUri'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-storage, dataproc

I am trying to create Data Proc cluster with following python packages.

"PIP_PACKAGES": "google-cloud-bigquery==3.10.0 google-resumable-media[requests]==2.5.0 google-cloud-storage==2.8.0 google-cloud-secret-manager==2.16.1 google-ads==21.0.0"

The Data Proc Cluster is built successfully but it gives me following error. Essentially, its not able to connect to the GCS Bucket from the cluster.

Server error: Internal server error: module 'google.auth.credentials' has no attribute 'CredentialsWithTokenUri'

On the other-hand, if I remove google-ads==21.0.0 package from the installation, it works fine and it is able to connect to GCS Bucket.

I am not sure whats happening and would appreciate your help.

1. Tried installing packages above without versions
2. Tried versions 12 through 15 for Google ads
3. Tried installing these packages in virtual environment

None of them is helping.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message and updated google-auth:

```
pip install --upgrade google-auth
```

It solved the problem from me.